# Basic doubts on generating package for Web Deploy 2.0 with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment, webdeploy, microsoft-web-deploy

I am trying to deploy a Visual Studio 2008 project to IIS using Web Deploy 2.0 and after reading a lot I am still lost. Nearly everything I found is about Visual Studio 2010 (maybe WebDeploy 2.0 is not compatible with Visual Studio 2008?). Here is my case:

All the info I am finding is related with Visual Studio 2010. Here is my scenario

- Solution in Visual Studio 2008 using C# and Framework 3.5
- Build server using Jenkins with Windows 2008R2
- SYSTEST server (were I want to deploy) with Windows w2008R2 + IIS 7.5

I am able to build perfectly my site in Build Server using MSBuild command (**MSBuild solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal /t:Rebuild**)

In order  to improve deploy I want to use Web Deploy 2.0. As far as I have read I think I have to:

1. Step 1- Generate Packages from MSBuild in BuildServer
2. Step 2- Use MSDeploy to deploy automatically created Packages to
   SYSTEST server

I am having problems in step 1.. so I tried several things

A) After building I try to generate packages (**MSBuild.exe solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal /t:package**) but it fails with:

> D:\sol\workspace\solution1.sln: error MSB4057: The target "package"
>   does not exist in the project.

B) I have read that I have to pass as parameter the csproj that contains website.. so I tried (**MSBuild.exe website\web1.csproj /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal /t:package**)

and fail again with same error:

> D:\sol\workspace\website\web1.csproj: error MSB4057: The target
>   "package" does not exist in the project.

C) I thought I might need Web Deploy 2.0 installed in Build Server(http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=209116) and installed it, but still same problem.

Anyone has any idea on what I am doing wrong? As far as I have read, all examples shows Package  generated from UI in Visual Studio 2010. My Visual Studio 2008 does not have even the ability to generate packages. I thought that installing Web Deploy 2.0 in Build Server were going to add target "Package" and allow me to use msbuild to invoke it..

Thanks